# Launch Two Applications with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion

I have been trying to launch two applications that I created with a single applescript file. (I am using OS X Lion)

The code I am using is:

```
tell application "app1" to activate
tell application "app2" to activate
```

Doing either one of these two tells works, but both together only launches the first application...

Does anyone know what I an doing wrong?

The first application is a C application compiled by xCode, and the second application is an AIR/Flash application created/published in Flash CS4

**Edit**

---

I've also tried

```
do shell script "my_path_here/app1"
do shell script "my_path2_here/app2"
```

which only launches the first application.

I've also tried:

```
do shell script "my_path_here/app1" & "; my_path2_here/app2"
```

which STILL only launches the first application.

**Edit 2**

---

I've discovered that this script will work:

```
do shell script "cd my_path_here/ ; open app1 ; cd my_path2_here/ ; open app2"
```

This accomplishes what I need done, but still leaves open the original problem, as this is a workaround and not a fix... This might shed more light on what the issue could be though.

Comment: I'm not going to make this an official answer, but I don't think AIR apps have Applescript support.  I did some searching for a definitive answer for you [and found this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22239/using-applescript-to-control-an-application-which-does-not-support-it).  One way to be sure is to attempt to open the AIR app with ScriptEditor and see if there's an AppleScript dictionary, which there likely won't be.

Comment: That makes sense, but since all I am doing is launching the applications, shouldn't that not be an issue? or at the very least using an applescript to run two shell scripts to launch the applications should work, but I've tried that, and it does the exact same thing.

Comment: Not to mention, I can successfully run the AIR app from the applescript, just not both applications at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that this script will work:

do shell script "cd my_path_here/ ; open app1 ; cd my_path2_here/ ; open app2"
This accomplishes what I need done, but still leaves open the original problem, as this is a workaround and not a fix... This might shed more light on what the issue could be though.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce the issue, so can't tell you why it's happening, but (assuming there's a timing problem) introducing a [delay](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=AppleScript/2.1/en/as306.html) between the application launches may resolve the problem. You'll need to experiment with the delay time.

```
tell application "app1" to activate
delay 10
tell application "app2" to activate
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work, however I did discover a do shell script that will work, I've added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "app1" to activate
end if

tell application "app2" to activate
end if
```

Try that and see how it works.

Comment: `expected end of line, etc. but found "if"`  <-- It gives me this error when I try to run it with those end ifs in there

Comment: Sorry, change it to from "end if", to "end tell".

Comment: same error but `found "end tell"` instead. I also tried doing this using `tell application "app1" \n activate \n end tell` etc.. and it still didn't work

Comment: Odd. I'll look into it some more.